# Redirect Outward of unix os commands to html page

Tags: linux, unix, command

How can i redirect and export unix os commands to HTML Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (using command ls):

```bash
# start the html file
echo "<html lang="en"><head><title>Command Output</title></head><body><table>" > output.html

# get the data needed to a file for processing
ls -lah >> output.html

# escape html entities with PHP (optional but recommended)
cat output.html | php -R 'echo html_entity_decode($argn);' > output2.html

# enclose each line in a html table row
while read line; do echo "<tr><td>$line</tr></td>"; done < output2.html > output3.html

# finish the file with the html closing tags
echo "</table></body></html>" >> output2.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, what i actully need is to redirect the -ls to be in html format with <table><tr><\tr> <\table>, is there any possible way to add these tags ?

Comment: I have edited my answer, it should do what you said now!